# "Enter the password 1234" vs. "enter 1234 for a password"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. Enter the password 1234.
> 2. Enter 1234 for a password.

Comment: 12344a is more secure... seriously, what's the context?

Answer (score 1):

*1)Enter the password 1234* means:

> The password is 1234, enter it.

*2)Enter 1234 for a password* could mean:

> Enter 1234 in order to obtain a password.

You could avoid this ambiguity by saying:

> 2)Enter 1234 *as* a password.

However, which is *correct* all depends on what you are trying to say.